# Detect change in JSON, send notification if change is detected

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, push-notification, notifications

Ex: let's say I have `test.json` with this format:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Bobby Anderson",
      "address": "123 River Dr",
      "occupation": "Data Analyst"
    },
    {
      "name": "Melinda Oliver",
      "address": "456 Lake Ln",
      "occupation": "Cashier"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to have a function that checks for a change every few seconds, and if a change is detected, send a notification with said change. Ex:

If `Bobby Anderson`'s `occupation` is changed to `"Programmer"`, send a browser notification: "Bobby Anderson is now a Programmer".

I have tried searching for this and nothing is coming up. I also tried using the `setTimeout` function to run a `$.getJSON` query every few seconds, but it is not working. thanks

edit: (my code)

```
setTimeout(function () {
  $.getJSON('test.json').then(function (data) {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
      $('body').append(`
        <p>`+data.data[i].name+`</p>
        <p>`+data.data[i].address+`</p>
        <p>`+data.data[i].occupation+`</p>
        `)
    }
    if (Notification.permission !== 'denied' || Notification.permission === "default") {
      Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
      if (permission === "granted") {
        /* Insert function that checks for a change in the JSON, and sends a notification if true */
      }
  });
  });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Edited @bassxzero

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification

Comment: Thank you @Taplar , I totally haven't been on that page before :)